# Kubernetes Persisent Volume

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Could anyone clarify on the Persistent Volume in Kubernetes?

In this below example, the /my-test-project is in the persistent volume.Then, why I need these mounts as technically my entire directory /my-test-project is persisted? How these mountpath and subpath would help if entire directory is persisted.Thanks!

```
volumeMounts:
    - name: empty-dir-volume
      mountPath: /my-test-project/data-cache
      subPath: data-cache
    - name: empty-dir-volume
      mountPath:  /my-test-project/user-cache
      subPath: user-cache

  volumes:
  - name: empty-dir-volume
    emptyDir: {}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `/my-test-project` entire directory is **not persisted**.

- mountPath or path in host `/my-test-project/data-cache` is persisted in `empty-dir-volume` in path `data-cache`
- mountPath `/my-test-project/user-cache` is persisted in `empty-dir-volume` in path `user-cache`

Which mean when you create files inside `/my-test-project/data-cache`, it will be persisted in `data-cache`(subpath) inside emtpy-dir-volume. Similarly for user-cache. Whenever you create files inside `/my-test-project/` it **wont be persisted**. Lets say you create `/my-test-project/new-dir`, now `new-dir` will not be persisted.

For better explaination, lets take the below example(two containers sharing the volume, but in **different mounthPath**):

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: share-empty-dir
spec:
  containers:
  - name: container-1
    image: alpine
    command:
      - "bin/sh"
      - "-c"
      - "sleep 10000"
    volumeMounts:
    - name: empty-dir-volume
      mountPath: /my-test-project/data-cache
      subPath: data-cache-subpath
    - name: empty-dir-volume
      mountPath:  /my-test-project/user-cache
      subPath: user-cache-subpath
  - name: container-2
    image: alpine
    command:
      - "bin/sh"
      - "-c"
      - "sleep 10000"
    volumeMounts:
      - name: empty-dir-volume
        mountPath: /tmp/container-2
  volumes:
  - name: empty-dir-volume
    emptyDir: {}
```

In container-1:

- mountPath `/my-test-project/user-cache` is persisted in `empty-dir-volume` in path `user-cache-subpath`
- mountPath `/my-test-project/data-cache` is persisted in `empty-dir-volume` in path `data-cache-subpath`

In container-2:

- mountPath `/tmp/container-2` is persisted in `empty-dir-volume` in path "" (which means "/")

Observations:

- touch `/my-test-project/user-cache/a.txt`. we can see this file in container-2 at `/tmp/container-2/user-cache-subpath/a.txt` and reverse will work
- touch `/my-test-project/data-cache/b.txt`. we can see this file in container-2 at `/tmp/container-2/data-cache-subpath/a.txt` and reverse will work
- touch `/tmp/container-2/new.txt`, we can never this file in container-1 as the base path we are have specified subPaths in container-1
- Play around similarly for even better understanding

Note: Just to be clear, you are using `emptyDir` type volume, which means whenever pod gets deleted, data will be lost. This type is used only to share the data between containers.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Your below line is not clear.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Your line - "Your /my-test-project entire directory is not persisted." is not clear. I'm using persistant volume and /my-test-project is in my persistant volume. Then, my /my-test-project  will be persisted correct?

Comment: @testbgtestbg Added more details. Please refer it